# Single Inheritance issue in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I tried to execute the below java code which demonstrates single inheritance.

```
class Box {
    double width;
    double height;
    double depth;
    Box(double w, double h, double d) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        depth = d;
    }
    double volume() {
        return width*height*depth;
    }
}

class BoxWeight extends Box {
    double mass;
    BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        depth = d;
        mass = m;
    }
}

class BoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoxWeight box = new BoxWeight(10,20,15,32.3);
        double vol;
        vol = box.volume();
        System.out.println("Volume = " + vol);
    }
}
```

But this raised the following error:

```
C:\User\Java>javac BoxWeight.java
BoxWeight.java:16: error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
    BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m) {
                                                      ^
  required: double,double,double
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Again when I modified the code in sub class constructor as below

```
BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m) {
        super(w,h,d);
        mass = m;
    }
```

it gave the desired output.

Why the first way didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the width, height and depth to the super class constructor:

```
BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m) {
    super(w,h,d);
    mass = m;
}
```

When the sub-class constructor doesn't contain the `super(...)` call to the super-class constructor, the compiler implicitly adds a `super()` call to the super-class parameter-less constructor, which doesn't exist in your `Box` class. That's the reason your code didn't pass compilation.

As Amongalen commented, if you don't define any constructor in your class, the compiler adds a default parameter-less constructor. However, once you define any constructor, the default constructor is not added. This means that your code could have passed compilation if you just removed the `Box(double w, double h, double d)` constructor (or kept that constructor and added an explicit `Box()` constructor).

Comment: Yes. I got the answer. Thank you @Sweeper

Comment: @ShashikanthReddy that's another issue - you can assign them in the sub-class constructor if the sub-class has access to them (though I wouldn't do that), but that wasn't the cause of the error you got. The cause was the implicit call to a non-existing super class constructor.

Comment: @Eran Might be worth adding a word or two about default constructor - that it's there if you don't declare any constructor, but it's gone if you define your own.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember a simple rule when working with inheritance

`Whenever any constructor of a child class is called the default constructor of the parent class is called automatically`

Now in our case when we invoked `BoxWeight(double w, double h, double d, double m)` constructor the default constructor of parent class i.e. `Box()` needs to be called automatically. But in our case `Box()` doesn't exist so we need to manually call `super(w,h,d);`. Here super is used to refer to the parent class.